# Maven: non-parseable POM

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven

I have created a [maven project](http://fruzenshtein.com/setup-of-dynamic-web-project-using-maven/) and now I need to add dependencies to my `dynamic web project`. 
So I added the dependencies named in that [spring tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/).

**Problem:** I get the parsing issue:

> Project build error: Non-parseable POM
>   C:\Users\username\Development\Spring\Projects\MyWebService\pom.xml:
>   Duplicated tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen
>   ...\r\n  \r\n  \r\n  ... @60:10)

My pom.xml looks like that:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MyWebService</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyWebService</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

eclipse marks that line:

[image]

**Question:** Why is it wrong to have multiple repositories in the pom.xml?

**Note:** Maven Version

```
Name: EMPEDDED, Details: 3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931 - for Name: WORKSPACE, Details: NOT AVAILABLE [3.0,)
```

Comment: Your pom.xml is well formed, maybe it is eclipse bug? Try to restart it, clean cache, etc.

Comment: The repositories element is inherited so you would usually specify the repositories to use for a group of projects by defining a repositories element at the top of your inheritance chain.

im guessing you declared that repository already in your inheritance chain: check your others pom

Comment: @Zeromus thank you for your hint. I have another project that uses some spring dependencies but it does not inherit repository. How can I achieve that repository is inherited only for the current project?

Comment: What version of Maven do you use in Eclipse ?

Comment: Name: EMPEDDED, Details: 3.3.9/1.7.0.20160603-1931 - for Name: WORKSPACE, Details: NOT AVAILABLE [3.0,)

Comment: I'm using standalone version of Maven (Apache Maven 3.3.9) and I don't have any problem with your pom.xml. The problem is probably coming from Eclipse.

Comment: @MickaelB I am using Spring Tool Suite. Version: 3.7.3.RELEASE
Build Id: 201602251025
Platform: Eclipse Neon (4.6) - What can I do to solve the problem? I have already restarted Eclipse and cleaned the project. Unfortunately none of them helped me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm seeing that in your error you have `\r\n \r\n \r\n`.

Could you please ensure that your `pom.xml` is correctly encoded in UTF-8 and not in ANSI ?

Comment: Okay, got the issue. The file was a UTF-8 without BOM. Converting it to UTF-8 did the trick

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the latest version of **spring boot** like below:

```
<parent>  
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>  
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>  
    <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, using Eclipse, arising after commenting out a dependency with <!-- and restoring it. Checked that the encoding is UTF-8. Restored the original POM. Updated/Rebuilt project. None of this helped.

What fixed the error: exiting and re-entering Eclipse.

Thank you, @user1516873, for your suggestion/comment on the question post.